# File::PCAP::Reader and Parsing Pcap files with Perl

Tags: perl, pcap

I have a question regarding this package https://metacpan.org/pod/File::PCAP::Reader i want to parse some offline pcap files using Perl and extract the source address and destination address and source mac and destination mac

trying the following to dump the packet but its in binary format is there a way to extract the source and destination addresses ?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::PCAP::Reader;
use Data::Dumper;
 
my $fpr = File::PCAP::Reader->new( 'my.pcap' );
 
my $gh = $fpr->global_header();
 
while(1){
my $tsec = $fpr->next_packet();

print Dumper(\$tsec);
Dumper($tsec)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `File::PCAP` doesn't have the capability on it own to dissect the packets in a pcap.

An alternative is the [NetPacket](https://metacpan.org/dist/NetPacket) module -- it can both read from pcap files and get access to the mac addresses and the ip addresses.

For example, this code shows how to dissect the ethernet packet to get the mac addresses, then extract the IPv4 packet from the ethernet packet (adding
support for IPv6 works along the same lines )

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::Pcap qw(:functions);
use NetPacket::Ethernet qw(:types);
use NetPacket::IP qw(:protos);

my $err;
my $maxpkts = 0;


my $filename = shift ;

my $pcap = Net::Pcap::open_offline($filename, \$err) 
    or die "Can't read '$filename': $err\n";
Net::Pcap::loop($pcap, $maxpkts, \&process_packet, '');
Net::Pcap::close($pcap);
exit;

sub process_packet 
{
    my ($user_data, $header, $packet) = @_;

    my $ether = NetPacket::Ethernet->decode($packet);

    # Only want IPv4 packets
    if ($type == ETH_TYPE_IP) {
        my $ip = NetPacket::IP->decode($ether);

        print "Src Mac $ether->{src_mac} Src IP $ip->{src_ip} -> Dst Mac $ether->{dest_mac} Dst IP $ip->{dest_ip}\n" ;
    }

}
```

When I save the above in the file `readpcap.pl` and run it I get this

```
$ perl runpcap.pl test.pcap
Src Mac 0050569b5015 Src IP 172.217.169.34 -> Dst Mac 00000c9ff01f Dst IP 10.20.228.41
Src Mac 00163e0002b8 Src IP 10.20.228.41 -> Dst Mac 0050569b5015 Dst IP 172.217.169.34
Src Mac 00163e0002b8 Src IP 10.20.228.41 -> Dst Mac 0050569b5015 Dst IP 172.217.169.34
```